# In SQLAlchemy how to merge multiple rows into one by converting unique column values into comma separated string?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

**Sample table**

| Invoice Number | Invoice Date | Item Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 12 Jul 21 | Foo |
| 1002 | 10 Jun 21 | Baz |
| 1001 | 12 Jul 21 | Bar |
| 1002 | 10 Jun 21 | Spam |
| 1001 | 12 Jul 21 | Eggs |

How can I write a sqlalchemy ORM query to fetch these data in the below format:

| Invoice Number | Invoice Date | Items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 12 Jul 21 | Foo,Bar, Eggs |
| 1002 | 10 Jun 21 | Baz, Spam |

I am connecting to a sql server database in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it with SQL-Server but I reckon that you could use the [string_agg](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_agg-function/) function.

The simpler version, if you can live with duplicate values in your comma separated list:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.sql.elements import literal_column

result = session.query(
  Table.invoice_number,
  Table.invoice_date,
  func.string_agg(Table.item_name, literal_column("','"))
).group_by(
  Table.invoice_number,
  Table.invoice_date
).all()
```

And, if you need to avoid duplicate values:

```
sub_query = session.query(Table).distinct().subquery()

result = session.query(
  sub_query.c.invoice_number,
  sub_query.c.invoice_date,
  func.string_agg(sub_query.c.item_name, literal_column("','"))
).\
select_from(sub_query).\
group_by(
  sub_query.c.invoice_number,
  sub_query.c.invoice_date
).all()
```